# Unable to start the Spring Cloud ZipKin Server

Tags: zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am not able to start the Spring Cloud ZipKin Server, It is giving below mentioned exception.

BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath

Below are my maven dependencies -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also my application startup class looks as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinStreamServer
public class ZipkinApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ZipkinApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Cloud Zipkin Stream is using Spring Cloud Stream underneath. You need to provide how do you want to send the spans to Zipkin - thus you need a binder. One possible binder is the RabbitMQ binder. Check out this: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/master/zipkin-server/build.gradle#L6

Comment: We no longer suggest running the server like thus

Comment: Please read more about this here https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-collector/rabbitmq/README.md

Comment: you can refer to the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046528/spring-initializer-zipkin-server-missing/53058877#53058877