# Spring Initializer - Zipkin Server missing?

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin

Can't see Zipkin Server when using Spring Initializer . Has it been removed? What is the alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Zipkin Server is not part of Spring initializers. You have to use the official release of the Zipkin server

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin#quick-start

And custom servers are not supported anymore meaning you can't use `@EnableZipkinServer` anymore since 2.7

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Lately I have been trying the same and couldn't find that option in initializer. I am just posting this if anyone encounters the same issues and lands on this page. You can refer below sample GitHub project which is consists of four micro services ( zipkin server, client, rest service, and Eureka ) using Edgware release with latest version of sleuth.

[Sample Zipkin Server/Client](https://github.com/iuprade/slueth-zipkin-server-client)

Answer (score 0):

Create spring starter project and add the below dependencies manually.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```